# How to access the response headers with Nuxt 3's useFetch?

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am migrating a Nuxt2 that uses Axios to a Nuxt3 App that uses [useFetch](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch).

This following code accesse the response's header:

```
$axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then((response) => {
    const responseFilename = response?.headers?.['content-disposition']?.match(/filename="([\w\d_\-.]*)"/)?.[1];
    const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
        type: response.data.type ?? response.headers?.['content-type'],
});
```

**How do I achieve this with useFetch ?** All I get is { data, pending, error, refresh, status }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the response headers using the `onResponse` interceptor.

```js
await useFetch('/api/', {
    onResponse(context) {
        // Output all available response headers
        console.log(context.response.headers)
        
        // Get the specific response header, e.g. authorization
        console.log(context.response.headers.get('authorization'))
    },
})
```

It will output the list of available headers in your terminal.

Tested and it works.

**Edit:** Get the header data from the interceptor

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const authorizationHeader = ref<string | null>(null)
await useFetch('/api/test', {
  onResponse (context) {
    authorizationHeader.value = context.response.headers.get('authorization')
  },
}) 
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    {{ authorizationHeader }}
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

Comment: Follow-up question: How do I transfer data from this interceptor to the actual result of the useFetch call? I need the value of a particular header after awaiting the result 

Comment: Hi, @Tim. I edited my answer and added an example of how to get it.

Comment: Hi, thanks but this is not what I need - I need the result in the return value of $fetch. However, I found this: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14575 